# Join based on substring operation

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two DataFrames, `a` and `b` with columns "Name" and "ID" respectively. What I'm trying to do is to find all the columns in `a["Name"]` that are a substring of a value in `b["ID"]` so that when I join `b` to `a`, the columns will match up. I have a guarantee that any value in `b` **must** match to at most one value in `a` but any value in `a` may match to any number of values in `b`.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Boomhaur", "Dale", "Bill", "Hank"]})

b = b = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["Boomhaur-2345", "Dale-999999", "Bill-000", "Bill-001", "Peggy-420"]})

a = # Some Pandas magic here...

a
#        Name             ID
# 0  Boomhaur  Boomhaur-2345
# 1      Dale    Dale-999999
# 2      Bill       Bill-000
# 2      Bill       Bill-001
# 3      Hank            NaN
```

Originally, I had multiple JSON files and a guarantee that `ID` would be unique for each, so I could do this:

```
a["_merge"] = a["Name"].apply(lambda x: x in data["ID"])
b = json.normalize(data["Data"])
b["ID"] = data["ID"]
b["_merge"] = True
a = a.join(b.set_index("_merge"), on="_merge")
```

This works, but now I'm trying to merge the files together into a single data frame and then join that to `a`, but I'm not sure how to do it once the guarantee of a set `ID` is gone. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are the `ID` values in `b` in a fixed format? That could simplify the merge if so.

Comment: @Nick No, they are not. At the least, I can guarantee that there is no leading or trailing whitespace and that if the substring operation will match with casing as-is. But, otherwise, there is no format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use regex, you could look for each `Name` value in each `ID` value, storing the index of any found `Name` values and then `join` `a` to `b` on that value:

```py
out = a.join(
    b.set_index(b['ID']
        .apply(lambda id:next((idx for idx, name in a['Name'].items() if name in id), None))
        .astype('Int64'))
)
```

Output:

```
       Name             ID
0  Boomhaur  Boomhaur-2345
1      Dale    Dale-999999
2      Bill       Bill-000
2      Bill       Bill-001
3      Hank            NaN
```

Note that where I've used `None` as a default for `next`, you can use any index value that doesn't occur in `a` (e.g. perhaps `-1`). If you do, you won't need the `.astype('Int64')` conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the matching occurences of Name in `a` from the `ID` column `b`. Then left merge the dataframe `a` with dataframe `b` on matching Name

```
pat = r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(a['Name'])
b['_name'] = b["ID"].str.extract(pat)

c = a.merge(b, how='left', left_on='Name', right_on='_name')
```

---

```
       Name             ID     _name
0  Boomhaur  Boomhaur-2345  Boomhaur
1      Dale    Dale-999999      Dale
2      Bill       Bill-000      Bill
3      Bill       Bill-001      Bill
4      Hank            NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Thank for this solution. However, I don't know that using a regular expression would be feasible here as there are many unique names in my data frame. Wouldn't that cause some issues with parsing complexity?

Comment: Regex would be fairly efficient solution here having said that if the pattern of ID in your dataframe is fixed like `word-number` you can use split instead of regex. In this case you can try `b['_name'] = b["ID"].str.split('-').str[0]`